# How to compute a correct MD5 for Fastspring API with Delphi and Indy components?

Tags: delphi, md5, payment-gateway

I need to integrate my application with Fastspring. I have written a key generator that receives inputs from Fastspring, through HTTP POST. The input includes a MD5 hash code, that I need to verify.

To verify the md5 hash, as per Fastspring specs, I use the following code:

```
// RawForm and cstr are delcared as string (delphi xe4)

RawForm := UTF8Decode(HTTPDecode(RawForm)); // Convert from utf8, http encoded, to Unicode string

tsl := TStringList.Create;  
tsl.StrictDelimiter := True; 
tsl.Delimiter := '&'; 
tsl.DelimitedText := RawForm; 
// sort parameters by name, using ordinal sort order. Note: not correct, but all names are lowercase for now
tsl.Sort; 
// Checked: At this point I do have a correctly decoded stringlist of http post parameters

// concatenate all values except the hash code
cstr := ''; 
for i:=0 to tsl.Count-1 do 
begin 
  if (tsl.Names[i]='security_request_hash') then 
    rmd5 := tsl.ValueFromIndex[i] 
  else 
    cstr := cstr + tsl.ValueFromIndex[i]; 
end; 
// concatenate the private key at the end
cstr := cstr + FASTSPRING_PRIVATE_KEY; 

cmd5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create; 
lmd5 := cmd5.HashStringAsHex(cstr);

Result := (Lowercase(lmd5) = Lowercase(rmd5));
```

The provided http post parameters, once decoded (http+utf8), are:

```
company=FooBar Inc.
email=vagif.samadoghlu@example.com
internalProductName=OBFUSCATED PRODUCT NAME
name=Вагиф Сәмәдоғлу
paymentprocessor=fastspring
product=OBFUSCATED PRODUCT NAME
quantity=1
reference=TEST_REF
servicekey=OBFUSCATED
servicename=OBFUSCATED
serviceversion=OBFUSCATED
subscriptionReference=SUB_TEST_REF
test=true
security_request_hash=84ffa39549f79a7be254b910217a47a7
```

*Note: Some parameter values were obfuscated for obvious security reasons. The form is provided to illustrate the data I'm working on, but you'll not be able to verify the content using the provided values and hash code.*

**The problem: I never find the same hash code as the one provided by Fastspring.**

How to use Indy to compute a correct md5 by providing a unicode string?
What is wrong with my usage of TIdHashMessageDigest5?

Using Delphi XE4 PRO

Note: Even is this question is specific to Delphi and Fastspring, this payment processor being widely used, a working md5 hash calc would be of interest to anyone that wants to integrate a delphi keygen with fastspring (there is no sample code on FS website, and they cant provide one)

[Edit] I have found that using another md5 function, the result is now identical to the one provided by fastspring. So I focus my question on the right usage of the Indy function.
See my answer for the alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have found out that a unit, provided with delphi enterprise, computes correctly the md5 hash, when a unicode string is provided.

Thanks to Jeroen, here:
http://wiert.me/2009/12/11/delphi-md5-the-messagedigest_5-unit-has-been-there-since-delphi-2007/

**The unit I used is located under (your delphi source root folder)\Win32\soap\wsdlimporter\MessageDigest_5.pas**

Please note that this unit is not available in the PRO edition, only in the Enterprise and Architect editions

I'm also a registered user of Delphi 2010 Enterprise edition, so importing the MessageDigest_5.pas unit was not a problem.
The md5 result with this unit is identical to the one provided by the payment processor, with this code:

```
  hash := MessageDigest_5.GetMD5();
  hash.Update(cstr);
  fingerprint := hash.AsString();
  lmd5 := LowerCase(fingerprint);
```

So, I have edited and focused my question to the right usage of Indy components to reach the same result (Indy being widely used, I guess this is not a bug, but a wrong usage from my side, maybe on unicode or encoding handling with Indy functions?)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, MessageDigest_5.pas seems to have been removed in XE4.  I'm using XE4 Enterprise and it isn't there (in \soap\wsdlimporter) anymore.  Too bad because I've been using it for a while.  Now I need another solution :(

just FYI